# What is the multi column condition syntax called ? since from which MySQL version?

Tags: mysql, sql

Syntax like this

```
select * from test where (id,val)=(1,'10');
update test set id=1,val='30' where (id,val)=(1,'10');
delete from test where (id,val)=(1,'30');
```

I don't find any syntax example from [select manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html), they don't describe the **where_conditions**'s grammer.

Is there any advantage to use this syntax ?

Comment: It might be more readable when used with multi-column keys. It makes more sense to use that syntax with `IN`, but then the indexes don't work...

Comment: I try to compare multi columns at the same time, this is different from `IN` clause.I use this to transform my data where I can got a full row data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL calls that syntax a *row comparison* and the parenthesised element a *row constructor*. I have seen this syntax supported for the *row subquery* since at least 4.1.

See [this reference](http://mirror.metrocast.net/mysql/doc/refman/4.1/en/row-subqueries.html).

Here's a link from a [more recent manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/row-subqueries.html). It has more to do with the syntax of the `=` operator than the syntax of the `WHERE` clause.